# How to draw a view in an ItemDecoration?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I know already how to draw things in an `ItemDecoration`, but now I want to draw a `View` in an `ItemDecoration`.

Since the setting is a bit complicated, I have created a [sample project](https://github.com/siralam/ViewItemDecorationProblem) that can reproduce the problem.

#### What I want to achieve

I have a `RecyclerView` with 20 items, displaying just numbers. I want to add a black header with the text "This is Number 5" above item 5.

*Of course, this is a simplified version of my real problem, and in my real problem I must do this by ItemDecoration, so please do not give alternatives that do not use ItemDecoration.*

#### The problem

As shown in the below screenshot, the decoration has correct size, and the first layer of the xml (which has `android:background="@color/black"`) can be drawn; but not the child views that include the `TextView` which is supposed to display "This is Number 5".

[image]

#### How am I doing this now

FiveHeaderDecoration.kt:

```
class FiveHeaderDecoration: RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

    private var header: Bitmap? = null
    private val paint = Paint()

    override fun getItemOffsets(outRect: Rect?, view: View?, parent: RecyclerView?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        val params = view?.layoutParams as? RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        if (params == null || parent == null) {
            super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
        } else {
            val position = params.viewAdapterPosition
            val number = (parent.adapter as? JustAnAdapter)?.itemList?.getOrNull(position)
            if (number == 5) {
                outRect?.set(0, 48.dp(), 0, 0)
            } else {
                super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(c: Canvas?, parent: RecyclerView?, state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        initHeader(parent)
        if (parent == null) return
        val childCount = parent.childCount
        for (i in 0 until childCount) {
            val view = parent.getChildAt(i)
            val position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view)
            val number = (parent.adapter as? JustAnAdapter)?.itemList?.getOrNull(position)
            if (number == 5) {
                header?.let {
                    c?.drawBitmap(it, 0.toFloat(), view.top.toFloat() - 48.dp(), paint)
                }
            } else {
                super.onDraw(c, parent, state)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initHeader(parent: RecyclerView?) {
        if (header == null) {
            val view = parent?.context?.inflate(R.layout.decoration, parent, false)
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(parent?.width?:0, 40.dp(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            view?.layout(0, 0, parent.width, 40.dp())
            view?.draw(canvas)
            header = bitmap
        }
    }

}
```

You can find other classes in the sample project. But I guess they are not really related.

As you can see, I am trying to layout and draw the view to a bitmap first. This is because I can only draw something to the canvas in `onDraw()` but not inflate a view (I don't even have a `ViewGroup` to `addView()`).

And by using debugger, I can see already that the bitmap generated in `initHeader()` is just a block of black. So the problem probably lies in how I  `initHeader()`.

Comment: You'll probably want to also measure the view before layout and draw, view?.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent.width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(40.dp(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY))

Comment: @Luksprog I just figured that out too. But still trying to position those child views in a correct position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out (Oops my bounty)

In order for a `View` to be created correctly, it needs 3 steps:

1. Measure (`view.measure()`)
2. Layout (`view.layout()`)
3. Draw (`view.draw()`)

Usually these are done by the parent ViewGroup, or in `addView()`. But now because we are not doing any of these, we need to call all of these by ourselves.

The problem is apparently I missed the first step.

So the `initHeader` method should be:

```
private fun initHeader(parent: RecyclerView?) {
    if (header == null) {
        val view = parent?.context?.inflate(R.layout.decoration, parent, false)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(parent?.width?:0, 40.dp(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        val widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(parent?.width ?: 0, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        val heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(40.dp(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        view?.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec)
        view?.layout(0, 0, parent.width, 40.dp())
        view?.draw(canvas)
        header = bitmap
    }
}
```

Note that the widthSpec and heightSpec will be different depending on your use case. That's another topic so I am not explaining here.